# How can I add G1 parameters into jetty scripts?

Tags: java, solr, jetty

I want to add Garbage collector's parameters like

> -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=65 \
>   -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=50 ...

from solr.in.sh into my jetty.in.sh ,how can I do it?is there any way to insert them into my jetty.in.sh or by command prompt?

Answer (score 0):

I added the jvm arguments of GC in the start.ini file of jetty.base and it worked. :)